# Jersey server - Trapping connection failure during response transmission

Tags: java, rest, timeout, connection, jersey

We've a RESTful **java** application developed w/ **Jersey**, deployed in a **weblogic 11g** on a **CentOS 5.7** box and available for mobile clients (**Android**) connections.

Sometimes, due to the mobile network, the response (200OK w/ payload) sent by the server doesn't reach the client that needs to handle a timeout exception; the server seems not to be aware of any problem.

Is there a way to trap server-side (in Jersey) this kind of situation?
I think that tcp should raise an exception that the http stack should handle and the Jersey as well.

Does an exception raise?

Thank you for your time
justme

Comment: I don't understand: can't you just catch a time-out on the client side? The server is fine, unless you want that it requires that the client confirms back it has received an answer (quite uncommon).